# WAMP, PHPMyadmin, Import, CSV Error SQL query... #2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Im getting this error:
Error SQL query… #2006 - MySQL server has gone away

I'm suspecting the CSV file might be the source of the problem as other CSV work, I've tried changing the following values on the SQL server

```
the key_buffer_size = 900M
max_allowed_packet = 900M
```

But it doesnt seem to fix the problem, I've tried converting the file to SQL, XML but it just doesn't want to import.

any advice?

Here are the files:

[CSV](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=05308798301359017369&t=0530879830135901736900812) im traying to upload
[CSV](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=35084734895689660868&t=3508473489568966086828063) that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I managed to import the file was to make smaller file and upload the one by one... which is strange as the csv wasn't that big 4MB thousand records...

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: My PHPmyadmin version is 4.1.14

Comment: This version is outdated, please upgrade.

Comment: Do you kbow if i Can upgrade on a wamp setup without corruption straight forward migration?

Comment: Please contact WAMP support.

Answer (score 0):

With phpMyAdmin 4.4.13.1 and the CSV import, I was able to import your file, after I changed the first line to:

﻿Username,Client Name,Date,Time,Published App,x